# How can I set up a headless version of three.js on a node server like the babylon.js-NulEngine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, three.js

I have been working towards creating a multiplayer three.js fps game and am planning to only do client-side prediction in the browser. On the other hand, I am using Node.js Express.js and Socket.io for the authoritative server-side implementation of the multiplayer game and would like to check collision server-side.

Using three.js or external libraries, what are the possible options to create a headless version of the game state like the babylon.js-NullEngine and calculate raycasting collision on the server-side?

Similarly, how do three.js multiplayer io-based games keep track of game states server-side and do bullet and movement collision?

[Edit] Extra reference to a post that answers this question elsewhere: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/using-three-js-how-can-i-set-up-a-headless-version-on-a-node-server-like-the-babylon-js-nullengine/9357

Answer (score 0):

You can use ammo.js or cannon.js for serverside physics.. you can probably run three on the server as well. To try it I would load it.. Not create a renderer, and try to build the scene. Then instead of calling renderer.render you would just do scene.updateMatrixWorld() each frame or something?

Comment: Would the server need to keep track of a list of three.Mesh objects for collision? Are there alternative object3D classes which do not have properties such as material and color and only make use of geometry and position